# Drawing Q–Q plots (pgfplots)

Tags: pgfplots

I can see from the PGFplots documentation, that there is no native support for [Q–Q plots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot).

However, since I am using PGFplots for *all* my other figures, I would also like to use it to display the Q–Q plots. The main reason is consistency.

I have a sample Q–Q plot plotted in R, which looks nowhere near my other figures:

[image]

Has anyone dealt with this situation? I have searched on TeX but the search does not yield relevant results. Either the search is faulty (searching for "Q-Q" is *very* inconvenient, even on Google), or there are no relevant questions/answers yet (on TeX).

Could this be done by using gnuplot? Or maybe plotting a native scatter plot with pgfplots and somehow transform the data beforehand? If yes, how?

Comment: You could produce it in R and then export it using the TikZdevice.

Comment: @alesc: Do you want to create normal probability plots, or some other distribution?

Comment: I don't see the issue here: this looks like a scatter and a line plot superimposed, which is easy enough. What does your raw data look like?

Comment: @Jake, I am looking into normal probability plots. The same as in the picture I provided for my question.

Comment: @JosephWright, this is not an ordinary scatter plot. The data is transformed beforehand. The original data follows the normal distribution. In the worst case scenario, I could learn how to transform the data myself and then plot it as an ordinary scatter plot. [Here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00310000000q000000) is a tutorial on how the Q-Q plot is constructed.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen: I have tried TikZdevice and am not satisfied with the output. There is a lot of tex code, dimensions are fixed in `pt` and everything is positioned absolute (also in `pt`). I will probably code my own data transformation and put the data in a `.dat` file and plot as an ordinary scatter plot. Does anybody have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using PGFPlots, although I would probably do this analysis outside of LaTeX (e.g. using R, Python, or Matlab), export the data as a table and plot that table using PGFPlots.

If you want to stay completely within LaTeX, you can first read, sort and count your data using

```
\pgfplotstablesort{\sorted}{datafile.txt}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
\edef\numrows{\pgfplotsretval}
```

Then you need a way of calculating the corresponding quantiles of the normal distribution, the so-called [probit function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Quantile_function), which requires the inverse error function. This can be [approximated with sufficient accuracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Approximation_with_elementary_functions) using

```
declare function={inverf(\x)=\x/abs(\x) * sqrt( sqrt( (4.3307 + ln(1-\x^2)/2 )^2 - ln(1-\x^2)/0.147 ) - (4.3307 + ln(1-\x^2)/2);}
```

Then you can define the probit function using

```
declare function={normq(\p)=1.4142 * inverf(2*\p-1);}
```

And that's all you need for the Q-Q plot:

```
\addplot [only marks, mark=*] table [x index=0, y index=0, y expr=normq(\coordindex/\numrows)] {\sorted};
```

[image]

Here's a full example using data generated with Python using `numpy.random.normal(size=100)*5+10`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}



\begin{document}


\pgfplotstableread{
1.46365192956
9.22330318663
15.4712651178
8.87219994452
9.92824632322
8.69935247007
17.8222081627
14.3601041144
22.9047131581
8.05005282649
9.650706465
17.2352199894
7.76424153088
10.370245979
7.12513239519
2.64730407495
7.2072208982
14.7683650153
14.0063750733
19.324137585
2.40858604381
18.0368674939
8.02681240716
8.26418810694
12.1941169594
9.62080674537
3.24961728242
3.27316960403
17.9038479307
7.40481579419
10.814441695
8.40741573499
6.08031313304
13.1781459953
10.206134367
15.0864695726
9.03013313987
4.46906993699
9.27542593922
11.387166818
5.34088290758
7.35790199406
11.8693581818
10.8557924873
13.969617244
10.6354692297
3.03046442179
6.60358722529
12.2836888554
8.46665782108
13.9221860476
15.1323993544
7.16507829073
5.69317421704
15.4624253296
16.9138444234
6.44259653768
16.4478862876
3.46926929558
10.8862152053
10.4982459647
13.079580222
10.8219448481
12.1887774019
2.27608579327
4.21879129366
8.6626149873
3.05616084556
12.2628717929
3.07385860151
12.1834370192
7.86785100457
22.3039915506
7.6084726129
-3.38040559575
-4.77264935147
13.9493967532
14.1237678197
6.79956429934
8.7032357113
6.08645967617
9.19491098171
17.1651582777
4.7041931405
3.78091331321
5.20247821499
13.8921717364
6.09560236506
18.5811121283
10.3758110312
8.95955605147
12.4511725524
4.67834498484
11.0234433275
15.364443589
8.23928346825
6.30079928878
9.95330967273
12.5692010856
11.8362767596
}\datatable
\pgfplotstablesort{\sorted}{\datatable}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
\edef\numrows{\pgfplotsretval}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={inverf(\x)=\x/abs(\x) * sqrt( sqrt( (4.3307 + ln(1-\x^2)/2 )^2 - ln(1-\x^2)/0.147 ) - (4.3307 + ln(1-\x^2)/2);},
    declare function={normq(\p)=1.4142 * inverf(2*\p-1);}
]
\begin{axis}
\addplot [only marks, mark=*] table [x index=0, y index=0, y expr=normq(\coordindex/\numrows)] {\sorted};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Nice code, I will probably use your formulas to transform the data in some other programming language in order to releave the latex compiler. I am currently looking into R code for `qqnorm` and `qqline` in order to find out how to reuse it for data transformation.